# Deform mesh without any modifier and shapekey: how is it possible?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shape-keys

This is a mesh created by an addon called [X-Muscle System](https://blendermarket.com/products/x-muscle-system).

This question is not about how to use X-Muscle System but about *how to implement this effect in Blender, without using modifiers.* It's to explore the possibilities of Blender. The addon is a working example I found.

[image: Basic Muscle created by the X-Muscle System addon]

I can drag the control point (an empty) around, and the mesh will deform along with it.

[image: Compressed basic Muscle created by the X-Muscle System addon]

But it doesn't have an armature or any kind of deform modifier. Actually, I removed all the modifiers/shapekeys/vertex groups. And I uninstalled the addon itself. But it still works!

How does the X-Muscle System addon work?
**What's the magic behind it?**

[image: No shape keys]

[image: No modifiers]

[image: No vertex groups]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just the bone.

You can parent a mesh to a bone and the mesh will follow the bone. That is, the bone controls the location, rotation, and scale of the mesh. It's good for armor, or make a bone control an eyeball to follow a target. It's also good for amination actions.

The *magic* here is the scale. If you scale the bone, it scales the mesh. Bones can have *Bone Contraints*, like the *Stretch To* constraint. This bone constraint stretches the bone along its Y-axis which lengthens or shortens the bone.

The object on the left in your screenshot is an *Empty* that is the *Stretch To* target. The thing on the right side is the armature with some bones and custom shapes. The muscle mesh in the middle is parented to one of the bones (*XMSL_Muscle_bone.L*) and this one has the *Stretch To* constraint (with a few others).

The *magic* bone (*XMSL_Muscle_bone.L*) is tiny and hidden in *Object* mode. Select the armature and switch to *Edit* mode and hide the big ones or uncheck *Bone Properties > Viewport Display > [_] Hidden* in *Object* mode.

Remove the bone constraint in *Pose* mode and the magic is gone ;-)

Comment: sure, I was faster, but you thought to try edit mode while I was confusing myself in pose mode.

Comment: I've noticed he use `Stretch To` etc, but I don't understand why the mesh doesn't have Armature modifier, nor vertex group. I thought they're needed for bone deformation?

Comment: Ok, I finally get it. It's not a "bone deformation" (like how we usually make animation), but a simple parenting relationship. It's just that simple, but somehow I forget you can parent an object to a single bone instead of the whole armature.

Answer (score 5):

It does have an armature.  The shape on the right is a custom shape for an armature `XMSL_Muscle SystemAmt` specifically the bone `XMSL_Muscle_flexor_bone`.

The vendor of the add-on has gone to lengths to conceal what techniques they are using, but they are using a combination of drivers and constraints to maintain volume.  They are probably also using a hook to make the controller work in object mode.

Comment: Oh, you were faster :D